# Bootstrap cols layout based on device resolution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3, I have 3 columns, like so:

```
<div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">3</div>
</div>
```

Cols are 33% for large devices and desktops, then 50% on tablets and 100% on mobile. When it gets to desktop (768px-992px I think is the classic Bootstrap breakpoint), I need the third column to go beneath the first two and center in the middle of the screen.

How can I do that?

Later edit: I've managed to add another class to the third col:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 myclass">3</div>
```

Then alter my theme's media queries

```
@media all and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .myclass {
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}
```

But I still hope there's another way, without altering Bootstrap default classes. Any other thoughts?

This is what I need: http://s12.postimg.org/9xynp7mod/layout.png

Comment: Not without Javascript, in that case I'd try centring as usual using CSS, or adding two more temp div's before() and after() the last div of col-sm-3 (to pad it out using only bootstrap)

Comment: So you're suggestion adding an offset via javascript to the last col on smaller screens? Not possible via css even if I try to wrap somehow around some of the cols first?

Comment: I've added another class in theme's css and made that margin-left: 25% on @media all and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 992px)

Comment: @DeanMeehan Why would you need Javascript for this?

Comment: @designarti desktop is 992 and above, do you mean at tablet size you want it like this?

Comment: Like this: http://s12.postimg.org/9xynp7mod/layout.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points to note first:

1. Try to think mobile first, it really helps with Bootstrap. So put the mobile classes first.
2. You don't need to specify all sizes, the smallest size will apply. For example, just use `col-xs-*` and `col-lg-*` and the sizes `sm` and `md` will be the same as `xs`.
3. Make sure you follow Bootstrap standards and use the correct class hierarchy. You are missing the `row` div.

To solve your problem now, your code looks like below. Note that you can nest `row` elements:

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-lg-4 red">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-lg-4 blue">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3 col-lg-push-0 col-lg-12 green">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Point 1. 2. and 3. are already worth upvoting, every 2nd question about bootstrap has it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the effect I think you're looking for using Bootstrap's col-offset classes, with something like the following

```
<div class="red col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0"></div>
<div class="green col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="blue col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-0"></div>
```

They essentialy add a margin to the left of the element in question equal to that many columns of content, in the same way you are in your example code. As for the vertical spacing, that you would have to add manually unfortunately, as Bootstrap doesn't really do anything about vertical alignment.

See https://jsfiddle.net/zwoL2uwe/1/ for a working example, and http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting for details of column offsetting in the docs

Answer (score 0):

add col-sm-push-4 to the 3rd. Like this:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">This is Div 1</div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">This is Div 2</div>
          <div class="col-sm-push-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">This is Div 3</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

You may need to play with the numbers a little to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Not working... see the image with what I need to achieve http://s12.postimg.org/9xynp7mod/layout.png